# Is there a way to set filename as column names automatically?

Tags: r, tidyverse, readxl

I am relatively new to R. I have a folder with many files (e.g. 5m.xls, 10m.xls,...) . I use map_dfc to read the files (see code below) and put them in one table. the files contain a table of 2 columns (x,y).
the table I get after running my code contains columns named x1,y1, x2,y2,.......
Thus I can't identify from which file it comes.
I want to set the column name as the name of the file from which it is read, so I tried this:

```
file_list <- list.files("folder", full.names=TRUE,pattern = ".xls")
files<-tibble()
files<-map_dfc(file_list,.f=read_excel ,col_names=c("nm",file))
```

But I get the columns named with same file name.
does anyone have an idea how I can do this automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pull the file names from the character elements of `file_list` using a regular expression, and add them as an extra column to each imported data frame, or to set new column names.

*Note that I use `.xlsx` instead of `.xls`. When I use the latter I get an error for some reason (probably an issue with writing to `.xls`). Make sure you change the suffixes to work with your files.*

First, libraries and data:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
library(writexl)

dir.create("folder")
walk(1:4, ~ write_xlsx(tibble(x = sample(10, 5), y = sample(10, 5)),
                       str_glue("folder/file{.}.xlsx")
                       )
         )
```

To get the data frame format you are asking for you can do something like this:

```r
map_dfc(file_list, ~ {
    df <- read_excel(.)
    set_names(df, paste(str_match(., "/(.*?)\\.")[,2], names(df), sep = "_"))
})
```

This will return a "wide" data frame that looks something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 8                                                                                                     
  file1_x file1_y file2_x file2_y file3_x file3_y file4_x file4_y
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1       8       9       5       3       3       6       3       9
2       3       5       8       6       7       5       2       5
3       4      10       7       2       8       2       7       1
```

But this type of data frame isn't very useful if you want to summarize with `dplyr` or visualize the data with `ggplot2`. I would recommend that you try "long" format instead. Put `read_excel` in a call to `mutate` that adds a variable with the extracted file names:

```r
file_list <- list.files("folder", full.names=TRUE, pattern = ".xlsx")
map_df(file_list, ~ mutate(read_excel(.), file = str_match(., "/(.*?)\\.")[,2]))
```

You should end up with a data frame that looks something like this, where observations are grouped by file name:

```
# A tibble: 12 x 3                                                                                                    
       x     y file 
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1     8     9 file1
 2     3     5 file1
 3     4    10 file1
 4     5     3 file2
 5     8     6 file2
 6     7     2 file2
 7     3     6 file3
 8     7     5 file3
 9     8     2 file3
10     3     9 file4
11     2     5 file4
12     7     1 file4
```

Comment: @NawDH good to hear. Can you click √ to the left to accept the answer so other also know what worked for your?